# How can I determine the nearest IP address from certain IP address

Tags: networking

I have 3 IP addresses.

- source IP : IP1
- target IP : IP2, IP3

How can I determine what target IP is the nearest one from source IP by C-code

I don't need to know exact locations of IP addresses.

Just want to know what target IP is the nearest.

Please give me some advices.

Thank you.

Comment: Neareast geografically or by bit mask?

Comment: nearest by bit mask. thank you

Comment: Are you looking for code or just a method?

Comment: If there is some code or method, it is the best....\\if not, i want to know just an algorithm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ip is in form

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd - 4 components.
```

First you should process 1st component:

compare `(source.aaaa - target1.aaaa)` and `(source.aaaa - target2.aaaa)`

(by module, so diffs are always positive)

If both are equal, then proceed with next component.

If different - the one with smaller difference is the closest one.

Comment: If this really helps you, then make this answer as accepted - this is how this site works ;)

Comment: Is this really what you're looking for? The one that is numerically closest? If so, why? Hard to imagine. Or are you really looking for whether one of the targets is in the same subnet as you?

Answer (score 0):

Use traceroute?

```
$traceroute <IP ADDR>
```

Should return hop information and speed, assuming you have the IP Addresses themselves